# Disable "displaying over other apps"

Tags: adb, notifications, system, 8.0-oreo, emui

On most Android 8 phones you can remove these persistent and annoying notifications from the notification center.

My phone with the EMUI skin cannot:

[image: image of settings with no switch]
<sup>image of settings with no switch (click to enlarge)</sup>

I'm wanting to disable them either with an app, probably with permissions granted with adb, or directly from adb.

I know they are managed by "Android system" what I don't know is anything to disable the notifications externally hopefully without root or custom rom